# what's the '/sys/class/net' equivalent for windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I'm working a little project that switches from `/sys/class/net` (linux) and the windows equivalent of what the linux version is.

using `process.platform` to detect if its `win32` or `linux` to switch between the two.
My issue is I don't know the windows equivalent to the linux version of `/sys/class/net`.

Can someone help me here?

**Edited:**

The purpose of this task is to pull the `interface` name and then proceed to retrieve RX/TX from this interface.

Comment: You're going to need to tell us exactly what information you're getting from under that hierarchy and what you want to do with them.  For example, if you are just taking the interface names and then performing an operation, we need to know what operation it is, because Windows probably does it completely differently.

Comment: @bk2204 Thanks for that information, I didn't realise that my question was somewhat sceptical so a better description has been provided.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent of `/sys/class/net` under Windows. There are probably APIs to get the information you want.

Comment: Rough guess and I haven't looked but search about WMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell `Get-NetAdapters` to enumerate your network interfaces and `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` to retrieve the TX/RX statistics.

```
PS C:> Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name Wi-fi

Name             ReceivedBytes ReceivedUnicastPackets       SentBytes SentUnicastPackets
----             ------------- ----------------------       --------- ------------------
Wi-Fi               7698820137                8290850      1511125034            5317861
```

You can also use `wmic` to get this information.

Update in response to additional question by OP to filter out the "junk". There are many ways to achieve what you want. Here is one:

```
PS C:> (Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name Wi-fi | Select ReceivedBytes, SentBytes | Format-Table -hidetableheaders | Out-String).trim()
7698820137    1511125034 
PS C:>
```

Comment: How would I filter out the "junk" to get just the number values?

Comment: @Johnty One of the cool things about Powershell is that all of the data is sent and received as the data itself, not text. The table format in the answer above is actually the output of the Format-Table cmdlet. You can pipe the data into select or store it in a variable and use the variable as an object or write your own cmdlet or powershell function ... lots of options.

Comment: @ZanLynx thank you for that input, I was unaware that there was possibilities in such as piping the data and then filtering out what I need from it.